# Monero GUI is unable to finish the synchronization

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, blockchain, synchronization

The Monero GUI (updated) suddenly stopped synching and stuck on the last 30 blocks or so.

Here the log: https://paste.fedoraproject.org/paste/uguNJ3qVqHmdvFvpc-vyOQ

What can I do to solve this issue?

Comment: Please don't post long logs as part of a question. Paste a link to them uploaded to a site such as Pastebin.

Comment: Which remote node are you using? Which version of the wallet?

Comment: the log can't be found...